# Convert SQL query result to C# Dictionary in LINQPad

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linqpad

Let's say I have the following data in an SQL table:

```
ID  A1  A2
0   1   abc
1   2   def
2   1   ghi
```

I have a query:

```
SELECT ID, A2 FROM MyTable WHERE A1 = 1
```

This will return two records, IDs 0 and 2.

I'd like to run this query in LINQpad, and return the results as a Dictionary collection. Obviously the key will be ID, and the value will be the value of A2.

LINQpad is connected up to the DB with the "Connection" dropdown in the top right. I am in "C# Program" mode, I think this is causing issues as every example I've tried seem to be in statements or expression mode. I want to get it working in Program mode though so I can run this from other Programs.

Comment: `Enumerable` has a `ToDictionary()` method, so what data structure are you working with? Are you running an ADO.Net query or are you using LinqPad's default Linq to SQL?

Comment: Program mode is effectively the same as statement mode if all the statements are put in the main method. If you can get it running in statement mode you should be able to transfer it to program mode trivially.

Comment: Also show us code. And tell us where exactly is your problem? Can you not get data from database? Can you not get it into a dictionary? Is it just that you can't get it working in program mode? Its hard to give targeted advice without seeing what you've done.

Comment: Why use linqpad when you can easily get the dictionary using straight c# linq.

Comment: Sorted guys, see accepted answer. Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to add a connection to your database in the LINQPad dropdown. If your table is called MyTable this will give you access to a LINQPad object called MyTables. Now the following code (in LINQPad C# Program Mode) should return a Dictionary Object:

```
void Main()
{

    var result = MyTables
                .Where(mc => mc.A1 == 1)
                .ToDictionary(m => m.ID.ToString(), 
                              m => m.A2.ToString());
    result.Dump();
}
```

> Responding to James Curran, you don't need the .ToString() amended
>   below:

```
void Main()
{

    var result = MyTables
                .Where(mc => mc.A1 == 1)
                .ToDictionary(m => m.ID, 
                              m => m.A2);
    result.Dump();
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was hoping for. Thanks! I was trying that earlier but I didn't add the 's' to the end of the table name.

Comment: One final question, could I ask what m and mc stand for?

Comment: @dahui take a look at this description of Lamda Expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-use-lambda-expressions-in-a-query ,mc & m could be called a and b, they stand in for the MyTable object in the lamda expressions. so Where(mc => mc.A1 == 1) means filter the MyTables list where MyTable.A1 equals 1.

Comment: Thanks again Steve. I am familiar with (the very basics of) Lambda expressions, I was wondering if your choice of mc and m stood for anything in particular in this case.

Comment: @dahui no they don't stand for anything just happened to be what key I hit on the keyboard :)

Comment: :D OK! Thanks again!

Comment: Why the `.ToString()` on the items?  `A2` already is a string, and why not let `ID` remain an `int`?  The ids that he'll be looking up in that dictionary are probably `int`s.